# Cannot resume Bitlocker encryption after restart (the device is not ready)

Tags: windows, hard-drive, encryption, bitlocker, device-manager

I have an issue in my hard drive and I found it hard to fix. Every time I plug in my hard drive Bitlocker popup window appears says "Encryption has been paused". It pauses at 1.6% and every time I click resume, also another popup says "E:\ The directory name is invalid", and when I do any action it says to me "The device is not ready".

I have a lot of personal data encrypted they represent memories. Among the solution that I tried is to open CMD and type

```
chkdsk
```

I was trying to encrypt my USB external hard drive (1 TB, mounted to E:) using BitLocker, and after the encryption got 10.1% finished, I accidentally shut down the computer. After restarting, I tried to resume the encryption, but it gives me an error: "Encryption could not be resumed. The device is not ready."

I've tried using >manage-bde -resume E: but it returns the same error with code 0x80070015. I also get the same error if I try to go to the control panel and turn off BitLocker.

Running >chkdsk E: shows several corrupt attribute records, but I haven't tried running that with /F since I'm worried that might make it difficult to properly decrypt BitLocker.

Are there any recommendations on how to either resume the encryption or decrypt the 10.1% it has already done? I've heard there's a BitLocker repair tool, but I don't have an empty 1 TB drive to use for that.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I assume you didn’t suspend the encryption before you shutdown your system that first time?

Comment: Yeah, I guess so, any solution please?

Comment: There really isn't a solution to a corrupt BitLocker disk header (which is most likely what has happened).  You should restore the data from your backup